# Hiding process from process list

Tags: unix, command, ps

How do I hide the name of process from process list and from /proc/pid/cmdline.
If process name is seen in process list then it is fine, but arguments of it should not come in the list.
Cause arguments contain the plain-text password and/or few sensitive information, that I wanna hide.

TIA,
Satish

Comment: Don't provide the password as a command-line argument.

Comment: You should post this question on: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: No, this is fine on stackoverflow, I think. It asks a specific technical question which can most reasonably be solved by programming; not an end-user question (the end-user cannot, in fact, solve this problem properly without altering the program to take its passwords via an alternate method)

Comment: What unix? Perhaps there's a distribution specific alternative available.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot hide it. This is the reason why so many good CLI programs just do not offer to provide a password at the command line.

There is software out to hide processes and it is know as rootkits, because they want to hide.

A better way to give a password is by providing a file only readable by the process user, and store the password there. This is e.g. done by mount, with the credentials option.

Comment: If I use the rootkit, then there are many other tools, like unhide,chkhunter to find out the process name and it's arguments. So I am looking for another solution.  But thnx for you help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't pass sensitive information on the command line. Pass it in environment variables*, or in the content of a file, or pipe it in via a file descriptor.

It is possible to modify the command line after a program starts (by overwriting the memory pointed to by argv[1]), but this leaves a window of vulnerability between when the program starts and when its arguments are erased. You cannot avoid this in general. So don't use program command line arguments for any sensitive data.

* - The security of environment variables may vary between unixes. On Linux it should be safe - if you have the ability to read env variables, you also have the ability to read process memory directly.

Comment: -1 The environment variables of a process can be read out, too, so this is not an option.

Comment: @Daniel, on linux at least, env vars can only be read by the same user - who could simply ptrace() in and read process memory directly anyway even if you managed to hide the information somehow!

Comment: +2 @bdonlan: I just checked and wasn't aware of this. Do you know how it is on windows? Only got a mac around currently.

Comment: @Daniel, Don't know about windows for sure - but running process explorer without elevation results in it being unable to obtain the environment for SYSTEM processes.